# When creating a Sass mixin, can I use a variable within an :nth-child declaration?

Tags: variables, sass, mixins, css-selectors

This is the mixin I wrote (.scss format), but I'm getting this error:

> Invalid CSS after "($x) ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "{"

```
@mixin x_cards_wide($x) {
  .card {
    &:nth-child(-n + $x) { margin-top:   0; }
    &:nth-child($x *  n) { margin-right: 0; }
  }
}
```

Check it out on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AcflC)

Comment: Remove the curly brackets and see if that helps. IIRC, SCSS uses brackets, but SASS does not.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. It's .scss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [interpolations](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
@mixin x_cards_wide($x) {
  .card {
    &:nth-child(-n+#{$x}) { margin-top: 0; }
    &:nth-child(#{$x}n) { margin-right: 0; }
  }
}
```